# Why is this Vue JS method function validEmail not definded

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

The function validEmail throws the following error.
"error  'validEmail' is not defined"

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      accountEmail: "",
      accountEmailVerify: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    validateEmail() {
      validEmail(this.accountEmail);
    },
    validEmail(email) {
      var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      return re.test(email);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `this` to refer to your component instance in order to access that method :

```
  methods: {
    validateEmail() {
      this.validEmail(this.accountEmail);
    },
    validEmail(email) {
      var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      return re.test(email);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you.  Have several examples of not needing it.  Wierd.

Comment: maybe they declared their functions outside the component.

Comment: @rjcarl i see that method is declared inside the methods option

Comment: @MichaelHarding i don't understand what do you mean?